# set the counter for a new environment

Tags: environments, counters, setcounter

I am writing an article that has lots of algorithms and protocols.I have defined the protocol environment and I want its counter to be different from the algorithm's counter. The first lines of that part of my code that defines the protocol environment are as below :

```
\documentclass[../main/main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document}
\newcounter{Protocol}
\newenvironment{Protocol}[1][htb]
  {   

  \renewcommand{\algorithmcfname}{Protocol}% Update algorithm name
   \begin{algorithm}[#1]%
  }{\end{algorithm}}

%%% Coloring the comment as blue
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}

\SetKwInput{KwInput}{Input}                % Set the Input
\SetKwInput{KwOutput}{Output}              % set the Output
\begin{Protocol}\label{prot:Forward_Path_Discovery}
\DontPrintSemicolon
  
  \KwInput{a,b}
  \KwOutput{c,d}
  
   \For{something}
        {
        \If{something}
        {
            something
        }
     }

\caption{Forward Path Discovery protocol}
\end{Protocol}

\end{document}
```

I used the `\newcounter{Protocol}` but in my main file, the counter of the protocols and algorithms are the same. I mean at first I have 1 algorithm with counter 1 and then I have my first protocol but ist counter is 2 instead of 1. what can I do to have separate counters for algorithms and protocols?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](https://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of code snippets. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: How about creating a `algorithm` counter? Also it isn't totally clear where the `algorithm` environment comes from.